# Select the max and second max value from a select, and group them?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

I've been battling with this problem for a week now and I need help.

I have a select statement that generates a table showing every product, and an import date per product.

How can I make a new table that shows:

- Product in one column.
- Last date in another column.
- Date before the last in the last column.
- **And group them by product.**

I've scoured the net for information, and I can't get it to work. Most of the examples show how to find **just one** second last value from a table. **I'd like to show it per product.**

Also, I can't use LIMIT due to using MSSQL.

**Table from query**

[image: Result of query]

**Query**

```
SELECT
    S.acIdent AS Product,
    CAST((SELECT top 1 adDate FROM the_move WHERE ackey = MI.acKey) AS date) AS ImportDate
FROM tHE_Stock S
    LEFT JOIN tHE_MoveItem MI
        ON S.acIdent = MI.acIdent
WHERE
    ( S.acWarehouse = '00051' ) AND
    (
        ( RIGHT(LEFT(MI.acKey,5),3) = '100' ) OR 
        ( RIGHT(LEFT(MI.acKey,5),3) = '190' )
    ) 
ORDER BY 
    S.acIdent, 
    CAST((SELECT top 1 adDate FROM the_move WHERE ackey = MI.acKey) AS date) 
        DESC
```

Comment: What does your query have to do with your question?  What does your data look like?  I understand the specific question you ask, but not the data structure, results you want, or relevance of the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the interest. I posted the query just to show what I am doing, so I avoid potential errors. A solution may not work due to my original select statement ex. the `ORDER BY` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query using row_number and pivot as below:

```
Select Product, [1] as [LastDate], [2] as [Last Before Last Date] from (
    Select top (2) with ties *, RowN=Row_Number() over(partition by Product order by ImportDate desc) from Products
        Order by (Row_Number() over(partition by Product order by ImportDate desc) -1)/2+1
) a
pivot (max(ImportDate) for RowN in([1],[2])) p
```

Output using this query for your similar input as below:

```
+---------+------------+-----------------------+
| Product |  LastDate  | Last Before Last Date |
+---------+------------+-----------------------+
|  075031 | 2014-07-08 | 2014-06-19            |
|  075032 | 2014-12-09 | NULL                  |
|  075034 | 2016-03-10 | 2014-07-08            |
|  075036 | 2016-03-08 | 2015-09-08            |
+---------+------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Nice creativity.

Comment: Thanks John Pasquet

Comment: It works. Thank you @KannanKandasamy for the solution. Is there a way to pull data based on the date? Ex. Display the import prices in columns next to the dates?

Comment: How Price Column is there in source?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy There would be a third column in my example table that looks like Product | ImportDate | ImportPrice. Each row would have a price, and now I am trying to figure out how I can show the price for the dates (on the right) in your solution.

Comment: We can add ItemPrice in the inner query and do another pivot here... Do you require a sample for that?

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand you correctly, you need the acIdent, then the latest import date, then the second to latest import date.

The difficult thing is the second to latest import date. For this, you need to exclude the latest import date.

This might work:

```
SELECT S.acIdent AS Product,
    (SELECT MAX(adDate) 
     FROM tHE_MoveItem MI2
     WHERE MI2.s.acIdent = MI.acIdent) AS LastImportDate,

    (SELECT MAX(adDate) 
     FROM tHE_MoveItem MI2
     WHERE MI2.acIdent = MI.acIdent
        AND MI2.ImportDate != (SELECT MAX(ImportDate) 
                                FROM tHE_MoveItem MI3
                                WHERE MI2.s.acIdent = MI3.acIdent)) 
            AS PreviousImportDate,
FROM tHE_Stock S
    INNER JOIN tHE_MoveItem MI
        ON s.acIdnet = MI.acIdent
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use rownumber instead of max, to find both the last and secondlast date.

```
Declare @mytable table (productnr varchar(10), importdate date)
insert into @mytable values
('075031', '2014-07-08'),
('075031', '2014-07-07'),
('075031', '2014-07-06'),

('075032', '2014-07-10'),
('075032', '2014-07-09'),
('075032', '2014-07-06')

;with products_cte as
(select productnr,importdate, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by productnr order by importdate desc) rn
from @mytable
)

select t1.productnr, t1.importdate lastDate,t2.importdate SecondLastDate
from products_cte t1
left join products_cte t2 on t1.productnr = t2.productnr and t2.rn = 2
where t1.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you @Peter for the solution. It worked! Also, I managed to modify it and get additional values for the imports. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

One more option with `lead` and `lag`.

```
select productnr,importdate as lastdate,prev as secondlastdate
from (select productnr,importdate
      ,lead(importdate) over(partition by productnr order by importdate) as nxt
      ,lag(importdate) over(partition by productnr order by importdate) as prev
      from tbl
     ) t
where nxt is null
```

`lead` on the date for last row (ordered by importdate per productnr) would be `null` and `lag` gives you the previous date before the lastdate.

Comment: It works. Thank you @vkp for the solution. Is there a way to pull data based on the date? Ex. Display the import prices in columns next to the dates?