# Finding last and second last date and corresponding values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following schema ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a80f1/1)):

```
CREATE TABLE meters
(
    id int, 
    description varchar(10)
);

CREATE TABLE readings
(
    id int, 
    meterid int, 
    date date, 
    value int
);
    
INSERT INTO readings (id, meterid, date, value)
VALUES
    (1, 4, '20081231', 500),
    (2, 4, '20090203', 550),
    (3, 1, '20090303', 300),
    (4, 2, '20090303', 244),
    (5, 4, '20090303', 600),
    (6, 1, '20090403', 399),
    (7, 2, '20090403', 288),
    (8, 3, '20090403', 555);

INSERT INTO meters (id, description)
VALUES
    (1, 'this'),
    (2, 'is'),
    (3, 'not'),
    (4, 'really'),
    (5, 'relevant');
```

For each `meter.id` I need to find the latest reading date, value, and the value difference vs previous reading.

For the sample data my output would look like this (plus some other columns from `meters`):

| meterid | latest | value | delta value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20090403 | 399 | 99 |
| 2 | 20090403 | 288 | 44 |
| 3 | 20090403 | 555 | null |
| 4 | 20090303 | 600 | 50 |
| 5 | null | null | null |

I figured I could first create a query with the relevant info and then join with that, but I struggle with achieving that

I've tried to adapt this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44457989/12506486) but for each id I get 2 rows instead of one

```
SELECT 
    p.meterid,
    [1] AS [LastDate],
    [2] AS [BeforeLastDate]
FROM
    (SELECT TOP (2) WITH ties 
         *,
         RowN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.meterid ORDER BY date DESC)
     FROM   
         readings AS r
     ORDER BY 
         (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.meterid ORDER BY date DESC) - 1) / 2 + 1) a
    PIVOT
        (MAX(date) FOR RowN IN ([1], [2])) p
ORDER BY 
    p.meterId
```

I'm looking for ideas how to solve the double row issue, or if that's a dead end how to get my desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can just use window functions:

```
select m.id, r.date, r.value, r.value - prev_value
from meters m left join
     (select r.*,
             lag(value) over (partition by meterid order by date) as prev_value,
             row_number() over (partition by meterid order by date desc) as seqnum
      from readings r
     ) r
     on r.meterid = m.id and seqnum = 1
order by m.id;
```

No aggregation is necessary.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=38b0085598557df531706466aa1cae95) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEAD` to get the next value going backwards, and `ROW_NUMBER` to get the first row.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT *,
        delta_value = value - LEAD(value) over (PARTITION BY r.meterid ORDER BY date DESC),
        RowN = Row_Number() over(PARTITION BY r.meterid ORDER BY date DESC)
        FROM readings AS r
    ) a
WHERE RowN = 1
ORDER BY p.meterId
```

Comment: your code doesn't work for me, I get `Invalid column name ''delta value''.`  'delta value' is the result that I want to calculate, so I'm not sure how can LEAD work properly